# Updating the desktop icons after moving a manually-installed program

Tags: software-installation, executable, pantheon

I'm new here. I've installed a program manually and now I've moved the program files to a new location. How do I update the path of the program for my old launcher icons to work properly?

-- without symlinking.

I'm using Elementary OS.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to leave your launcher icons as they are and put a symbolic link in place of your old program that points to the new place:

```
mkdir -p /original/directory/of/program/executable
ln -s /new/path/to/executable /original/directory/of/program/executable
```

For example, if the executable was originally at `/foo/bar/baz` and you moved it to `/quux/blah/baz`, you should do:

```
mkdir -p /foo/bar
ln -s /quux/blah/baz /foo/bar
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I thought about doing it this way but i'm not sure how I feel about having symlinks lying around from old programs. What are the other options? I could just re-install I suppose.

Comment: @BriWard Surely symlinking is better than a full-blown re-install, no? Besides, this answer makes no assumptions about the way your launchers are implemented so it should work with different DEs/WMs/...

Comment: It's quicker certainly. But I'm completely OCD about the tidiness of my folders.

Comment: @BriWard To each their own, I guess...

Comment: I appreciate the help though, thank you!

Comment: @BriWard No worries. Would you mind specifying in the question that you don't want symlinks so that others know what you're looking for?